# MySQLi edit from php and errors

Tags: php, mysqli, notice

Here is the link for ***the*** big file: http://pastebin.com/ZREjJ2NK

The problem is as follows:

I get the same error:

> ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!

But all my fields are written. Then from `$bTag` till `$avatar` my variables are with Notices like

> Notice: Undefined index: blah blah Line begins at: 74 and ends at 78

If you wanna test the code here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `bTag` TEXT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `rank` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `avatar` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `signup_date` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=11
;
```

Comment: No one gonna see that piece of code. Paste relevant part of it here.

Comment: In your form, all of the input fields, except for your `email` field, have `name="lastname"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my problems. It was the Tags, one SQL problem and had to switch the redirect to the header towards the update page.